# Integral surgery on $S^2 \times S^1$

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

It is a well-known fact that $S^2 \times S^1$ can be obtained by $0$-surgery on unknot.

What about the $(-1)$-surgery on $S^2 \times S^1$? It seems the resulting manifold, say $W$, bounds contractible manifold.

But I cannot prove it yet or refutes my argument. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is true, with some points to clarify. First, you are presumably talking about surgery along a knot that generates the first homology (and hence fundamental group) of $S^1\times S^2$. Then the result of adding the corresponding 2-handle to $S^1\times B^3$ is contractible.  The construction (called a `Mazur manifold') goes back to Mazur's paper, A Note on Some Contractible 4-Manifolds, Annals 1961.

The other point is that framing as an integer is not a priori defined for a knot that represents a homology class of infinite order. But fortunately the statement is true for any framing (as in choice of trivialization of the normal bundle). I'd suggest some basic reading about 4-dimensional handle calculus, as in the book of Gompf-Stipsicz.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. To clarify the notion, let me ask you one more question. If we replace $S^2 \times S^1$ by $S^3$ and perform $−1$-surgery on $S^3$ (following your description), may we obtain a manifold bounding rational homology ball?

Comment: Not necessarily; it depends on the knot along which you do that surgery.  I actually think these questions are better suited to Mathstackexchange than to this forum.